# How can we achieve position accuracy with simple worm gear box.

Tags: accuracy, position

I am also proposing to use simple 40:1 ratio worm gear box with Input servo motor. I am having a dial of 1600mm diameter on output of the gear box which will rotate only in clockwise direction at max speed of 0.5 to 1 RPM. Want to rotate the dial at 10 degree interval. Planning to put incremental encoder on dial for feedback. Can I achieve position accuracy? Can't able to use zero backlash gearbox due to high cost.

Comment: it is impossible to answer your question. you did not state what the accuracy needs to be.  ... what is the dial made of? ... what is the purpose of the device?

Comment: Position accuracy required is 6 minutes.

Comment: Position accuracy required 6 minutes, dial / disc of MS steel, application is to cut rings in equal parts.

Comment: you could use a sensor to roughly position the disk and then mechanically guide it to its final spot. maybe use a magnetic sensor, with magnets positioned every 10 degrees. i guess that the dial would need to have a locking indent, of some kind, at 10 degree intervals. it would have to be pretty accurate, because 6 minutes translates to ~ 1.6mm distance along the circumference (if my calculation is correct)

Comment: Hmm... so you have an encoder on the back end, but your slop in the system puts the actuator out of tolerance.. How do you expect anything to be able to hold it in the right spot if you have that much slop?

Answer (score 1):

Put a second encoder or any motion sensing device on the output of the wormdrive. This way the motion control can learn the slop in the gearbox and adjust accordingly.